# UnitTesting-SearchMethod

Tags: java

I have a method that searches for an element using binary search. I have created two test methods to test it. The first one asserts that the index returned by the method is the same as the index I give during the test. And the second test method asserts that the method returns -1 when the element is not in the array.

Are those two methods sufficient?
I am using Java

Comment: You posted a similar question for sorting arrays minutes ago... If this is homework/assignment tag the question. Also there are great articles and book about testing (goggle) :)

Comment: if you want to test that your binary search is well implemented, then you should check that the number of iterations made to get the element in the array is less or equal to O(logn), where n is the size of the array, as is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: This is not a homework assignment. I am trying to learn as much as I can about Unit testing. And I do use google a lot, but when I get stuck somewhere I prefer to ask here as I always get the right answers.

Comment: Like I said for your other question, if this isn't homework, then why are you re-implementing [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Because I want to understand how stuff works!!! I know that code reuse is important but if you do not understand it whats the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these cases.

- The element occurs twice in the array.
- If the array stores objects (rather than primitives), then consider the case when the array has
  an element that is equal to the object that your searching for, but
  is not the same object.
- Searching for null.
- When the array has no elements.
- Searching for an element that's greater than everything in the array.
- Searching for an element that's less than everything in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your test results should coincide with the business and functional requirements of your application. It sounds like you've covered the "happy path" scenario. Now you'll want to focus on edge cases which may include something like having empty strings to search against or when searching for a "-1".

Comment: They do. I am jut curious to know if I should test for anything else.

Comment: Ok I am going to try that. Thanks